# Exact sequences of sheaves and isomorphisms between them

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory

Suppose we have an exact sequence $0\rightarrow \mathcal{F}'\rightarrow \mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathcal{F}''\rightarrow 0$ of sheaves, and an exact sequence $0\rightarrow \mathcal{G}'\rightarrow \mathcal{G}\rightarrow \mathcal{G}''\rightarrow 0$ of sheaves with $\mathcal{F}\cong\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{F}''\cong\mathcal{G}''$. Are we then able to conclude that $\mathcal{F}'\cong \mathcal{G}'$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question fails at the level of abelian groups. For example, let $F = G = \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \times \cdots$. Consider $F' = \mathbb Z$ and $G' = \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$. Using the obvious inclusion maps, we note that $F/F' \cong G/G'$. By taking the constant sheaves of these groups, we get the desired exact sequences of sheaves. Clearly, $F' \not \cong G'$ and hence $\mathcal F' \not \cong \mathcal G'$.

Answer (score 4):

No. For instance, consider $\mathbb{P}^1$ with coordinates $(x,y)$ and two morphisms
$$
f, g \colon \mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{O}(2),
$$
where 
$$
f = (x^2,xy,y^2),
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
g = (x^2,0,y^2).
$$
Both are surjective, but
$$
\operatorname{Ker}(f) \cong \mathcal{O}(-1) \oplus \mathcal{O}(-1),
\qquad \text{while} \qquad
\operatorname{Ker}(g) \cong \mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O}(-2).
$$